# Target class controller does not exist Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, class, controller, classnotfoundexception

I have been trying to fix this for a while now, for some reason, the program can not find the class controller, even though it is there. I have tried restarting the server, I have tried to use all kinds of uses. And it still does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Web.php:

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\todoListController;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/todolist', 'todoListController@show');
```

The todoListController:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class todoListController extends Controller
{
  public function show() {
    $tasks = Tasks::all();

    return view('index', [
      'tasks' => $tasks,
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `composer du` might help (du is short for dumpautoload). What is the exact error you get?

Comment: @brombeer I tried it but I still get the same answer

Comment: Its a typo, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing)

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel 8
need to use **use** class in head and that is you are using after that for routing

```
Route::get('/todolist', [todoListController::class, 'show'])->name('todo-list');
```

if dont want to use Class than

```
Route::get('/todolist', 'App\Http\Controllers\todoListController@show')->name('todo-list');
```

Comment: yes but he is not using controller class in route

Comment: Yes, its a typo. `Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\todoListController@show')->name('todo-list');`

Comment: In laravel 8 if you want to use controller class in route you need to use as `('/todolist', [todoListController::class, 'show'])` or if you are an old school coder than you need to specify full path of your controller  `('/todolist', 'App\Http\Controllers\todoListController@show')`

Answer (score 0):

It could be that too:

Look in the file: *RouteServiceProvider.php* in *app/Providers* and see if there is a commented line:
// protected $ namespace = 'App \ Http \ Controllers';
Uncomment and try again.